# Why is Firefox lagging so much?

Tags: performance, firefox, benchmarking, lag

I have made a simple PHP script and I am running it from my localhost.
The script does not use any sessions, cookies, databases or files. It just sleeps for 100 ms and measures how long it did sleep. The code is not important here, but anyway:

```
$r = microtime(true);
usleep(100000);
echo 1000*(microtime(true) - $r);
```

When I run this script in Chrome or Firefox I get results like:
99.447011947632
or 
99.483013153076

However- the script always renders within a second in Chrome but takes up to 4 seconds in Firefox!

Here is my benchmark from Tamper Data for Firefox:
[image: Tamper Data]

(Sorry it's not in English. The columns are from left to right: URL, Total time, Size, HTTP Status)

So there is something wrong with Firefox. What could it be? The problem affects other scripts as well.

Should I send any special HTTP headers for Firefox?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I am writing a chat and this lag makes it impossible to use it comfortably on Firefox. Maybe there is a way I can make it usable for Firefox users too.

Comment: The main problem Firefox seems to have is memory management. My coworker is actually working on a chat system at the moment, and he's been having issues with Firefox and RAM XD It's possible that jQuery is to blame in some way (perhaps not allowing resources to be freed when done) but essentially you should try being careful to not reference things you don't need any more.